# turn for in loops local variables into mutable variables

Tags: swift

I've this code that I made on playground to represent my problem:

```
import Foundation

var countries = ["Poland":["Warsaw":"foo"],"England":["London":"foo"]]

for (country, city) in countries {
  if city["London"] != nil {
   city["London"] = "Piccadilly Circus" // error because by default the variables [country and city] are constants (let)
  }
}
```

Does anyone know a work around or the best way to make this work?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can make `city` mutable by adding `var` to its declaration:

```
for (country, var city) in countries {
```

Unfortunately, changing it won't affect your `countries` Dictionary, because you're getting a copy of each sub-Dictionary. To do what you want, you'll need to loop through the keys of `countries` and change things from there:

```
for country in countries.keys {
    if countries[country]!["London"] != nil {
       countries[country]!["London"]! = "Picadilly Circus"
    }
}
```

Comment: that's not a cool feature from swift actually. I guess they still need some work for some situations, specially with dictionary manipulations. Anyway thanks for the answer

Comment: I think of it as the slightly inconvenient side-effect of a lot of cool features. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fix more in spirit of the original code:

```
    import Foundation

    var countries = ["Poland":["Warsaw":"foo"],"England":["London":"foo"]]

    for (country, cities) in countries {
        if cities["London"] != nil {
            countries[country]!["London"] = "Piccadilly Circus"
        }
    }
```

As @Nate Cook pointed out, mutate the `countries` value type directly if that is your intention. The `country` and `cities`* values are just temporary value type copies derived from the origin `countries` data source that live in the scope of the `for` loop. Swift making them let values is actually helping you to see this!

Note: I changed the name of the value from `city` to `cities` to clarify the semantics since it is a Dictionary that contains one or more cities.