# Cannot assign to property: 'item' is a 'let' constant (Swift 4)

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

I'm trying to create a cycle in a function i use to handle calls but i'm getting the error "Cannot assign to property: 'item' is a 'let' constant"

```
 func didReceiveResponse(response:NearbyCars?, error : Error?) -> Void {
        dount += 1
        if let error = error {
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
            let actionDismiss = UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
            let actionRetry = UIAlertAction(title: "Retry", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.loadPlaces(true)

                }
            })
            alertController.addAction(actionRetry)
            alertController.addAction(actionDismiss)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.present(viewController: alertController)

            }
        }
        if let response = response {

        self.response = response
        if response.status == "OK" {
            if let carsDownloaded = response.cars {
                 var number = numberCars / (categories?.count)!
                let quotient = numberCars / (categories?.count)!
                let remainder = numberCars % (categories?.count)!

                for item in (categories?.enumerated())! {
                    item.element?.availability = quotient + (item.offset < remainder ? 1 : 0)
                }      // HERE THE ERROR



            cars.append(contentsOf: carsDownloaded.prefix(number))

        if dount == numberCars { return }
        sortedArray = cars.sorted {
            distance(from: currentLocation!, to: $0.location!) < distance(from: currentLocation!, to: $1.location!)

        }
    }


             self.tableView?.reloadData()
           } else {
                let alert = UIAlertController.init(title: "Error", message: response.status, preferredStyle: .alert)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction.init(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction.init(title: "Retry", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.loadPlaces(true)

                    }
                }))
                 self.present(viewController: alert)
             }
            isLoading = false

        } else {
            print("response is nil")
        }
    }
```

at this line   `item.element?.availability = quotient + (item.offset < remainder ? 1 : 0)` while i'm trying to create a cycle that assign the rest of `numberCars / (categories?.count)!` to the categories (since now `var number = numberCars / (categories?.count)!` work only when there is no rest). How can i fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [turn for in loops local variables into mutable variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25793460/turn-for-in-loops-local-variables-into-mutable-variables)

Comment: this not help!!

Comment: @the4kman This trick no longer works in swift4.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight While this is true, the **question** is still a duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do a loop over a range and then access `categories` by index to get a mutable object:

```
for i in 0..<(categories?.count)! {
    var item = categories[i]
    item.element?.availability = quotient + (item.offset < remainder ? 1 : 0)
}
```

I would also recommend avoiding the use of force unwraps by guarding around `categories`:

```
guard let categories = categories else {
   //Handle a nil categories array here
   return
}
```